# localStorage problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

My store uses localStorage to store the cart. I've used this line to retrieve the value:

```
var kamat = window.localStorage.getItem("simpleCart_items"); alert(kamat);
```

This will retrieve something like :

```
{"SCI-1":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-1","price":20,"name":"Valkoinen hiilikuitu -teippi","size":"Tyhjä"},"SCI-3":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-3","price":4,"name":"Car Speaker -hajuste","color":"Sport Fresh"}}
```

And as I've stored it as a variable, I want to use it a bit later.

I want to add this before the final curly bracket (after variable kamat)

```
var toimituskulut = {"Toimitus":{"quantity":1,"id":"Toimituskulut","price":8,"name":"Toimituskulut"}};
```

I've tried this as it needs a colon between the items:

```
var kamatjatoimituskulut = kamat + "," + toimituskulut;
```

But won't work. And if it would, it would insert the contents of toimituskulut after the final curly bracket. So what would I need to do?

**EDIT**

I'm trying to edit it when a button is clicked:

```
$("#posti").live('click', function() {
        $(".maksu").slideDown(600);
        $("#posti").attr("disabled" , "disabled");
        $("#matkahuolto").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#posti").addClass( "selectedtoimitus" );
        $("#matkahuolto").removeClass( "selectedtoimitus" );
        $(".simpleCart_shipping").html(kamat);  
        var kamatObj = JSON.parse(localStorage["simpleCart_items"]);
        kamatObj['toimituskulut'] = toimituskulut;
        localStorage["simpleCart_items"] = JSON.stringify(kamatObj);


    });
```

But no, it won't add a thing.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gV88c/)

**So, if the local storage looks like this:**

```
{"SCI-1":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-1","price":20,"name":"Valkoinen hiilikuitu -teippi","size":"Tyhjä"},"SCI-3":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-3","price":4,"name":"Car Speaker -hajuste","color":"Sport Fresh"}}
```

**I want it to look like this when I click a button**

```
{"SCI-1":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-1","price":20,"name":"Valkoinen hiilikuitu -teippi","size":"Tyhjä"},"SCI-3":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-3","price":4,"name":"Car Speaker -hajuste","color":"Sport Fresh"},"Toimitus":{"quantity":1,"id":"Toimitus","price":5,"name":"Toimituskulut"}}
```

But doing `var kamatjatoimituskulut = kamat + "," + toimituskulut;`
would only output something similar to this, right?

```
{"SCI-1":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-1","price":20,"name":"Valkoinen hiilikuitu -teippi","size":"Tyhjä"},"SCI-3":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-3","price":4,"name":"Car Speaker -hajuste","color":"Sport Fresh"}},"Toimitus":{"quantity":1,"id":"Toimitus","price":5,"name":"Toimituskulut"}
```

Comment: what do you mean by it 'wont add anything', as far as I can see dystroy's answer should work? Do you mean when you get the value from localStorage again it doesn't contain 'toimituskulut'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two variables containing JSON strings, like this:

```
var kamat = '{"SCI-1":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-1","price":20,"name":"Valkoinen hiilikuitu -teippi","size":"Tyhjä"},"SCI-3":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-3","price":4,"name":"Car Speaker -hajuste","color":"Sport Fresh"}}';

var toimituskulut = '{"Toimitus":{"quantity":1,"id":"Toimituskulut","price":8,"name":"Toimituskulut"}}';
```

you'll need to parse those strings into json like so (I'm using jQuery):

```
var kamatJSON = $.parseJSON(kamat);
var toimitusJSON = $.parseJSON(toimituskulut);
```

and then add them together like so:

```
$.extend(kamatJSON, toimitusJSON);
```

and since it's an object, the order should'nt really matter if you access the values like:

```
kamatJSON.Toimitus
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LNptx/4/);

Comment: Tried it, without luck. Take a look at the fiddle I created, probably something in the button? http://jsfiddle.net/gV88c/

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to add a property to an object.

But what you have is a string, as localStorage only stores strings. It seems to be stored as JSON (which is the most obvious solution).

First you need to restore the object :

```
var kamatObj = JSON.parse(localStorage["simpleCart_items"]);
```

Then you may add a property :

```
kamatObj['toimituskulut'] = toimituskulut;
```

And then you may serialize it as string again to put it back in localStorage :

```
localStorage["simpleCart_items"] = JSON.stringify(kamatObj);
```

Comment: Did you check in the console, before and after, what localStorage contains ? And did you check the toimituskulut object ?

Comment: Yeah, I had the console open.

Comment: It's probably something in the button, as it won't add anything. I'll create a fiddle about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try This :
        $("#posti").live('click', function() {
                $(".maksu").slideDown(600);
                $("#posti").attr("disabled" , "disabled");
                $("#matkahuolto").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#posti").addClass( "selectedtoimitus" );
                $("#matkahuolto").removeClass( "selectedtoimitus" );
                $(".simpleCart_shipping").html(kamat);  
                var kamatObj = JSON.parse(localStorage["simpleCart_items"]);
var resultObject =JSON.parse((kamatObj).concat(JSON.parse(toimituskulut));
 alert(resultobjcet); 
localStorage["simpleCart_items"] = resultObject; 
            });
```

Comment: Nope. Content slides down, but localstorage is the same.

Comment: please try this and let me know what is coming in resultObject.      var resultObject =JSON.parse(kamatObj).concat(JSON.parse(toimituskulut); alert(resultobjcet);  localStorage["simpleCart_items"] = resultObject;

Comment: @Pushpendra - probably the line that tries to use concat for json objects, as concat is for arrays ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add content to an object (stringified of course), in local storage, I wrote a tool just for that purpose. It can set any type of value in local storage, and extract likewise.  It can even store values nested deep within the stored values. You can find the script/tool here at https://github.com/andresgallo/truStorage

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [localDataStorage](https://github.com/macmcmeans/localDataStorage). It transparently sets/gets Arrays, Booleans, Dates, Floats, Integers, Strings and Objects. It provides lightweight data obfuscation (for security) and intelligently compresses strings. The utility lets you query by key (name) or (key) value or data type, checks for duplicate values, and supports the notion of write-protected keys. Note: *I am the author of the utility.*